# When I authenticate with spotify my URL returns this http://localhost:8888/login#error=state_mismatch

Tags: node.js, spotify

When I click the authenticate with spotify button it throws that in the URL. My spotify URI's are the same and my state values are also the same when they are returned. I have validated everything. Not sure if my authentication is following spotify's flow but based on previous code I have that worked it seems like it does. This is my spotify URI's from my developer dashboard
http://localhost:8888/callback/

```
    const client_id = '; // Your client ID
const client_secret = ;
const redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8888/callback/'; 
const openaiApiKey =     

const spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({ clientId: client_id, 
clientSecret: client_secret });
const chatGpt = new openai.OpenAIApi(openaiApiKey);
const sentiment = new Sentiment();

const stateKey = 'spotify_auth_state';

const session = require('express-session');
app.use(session({
  secret: 'your_secret_key',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));

let access_token;
let refresh_token;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

     
const checkAccessTokenValidity = (req, res, next) => {
  if (!access_token) {
    return res.status(401).send('Access token is missing.');
  }

  const options = {
    hostname: 'api.spotify.com',
    path: '/v1/me',
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token },
    method: 'GET'
  };

  const accessTokenReq = http.request(options, (response) => {
    if (response.statusCode === 401) {
      // Access token expired, refresh the token
      refreshtoken();
    }
    next();
  });

 accessTokenReq.on('error', (error) => {
  console.error('Error checking access token validity:', error);
  res.status(500).send('Intervl server error');
 });
accessTokenReq.end();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code mixed Spotify and OpenAI. I focus the Spotify.
And keep using [`spotify-web-api-node`](https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node/tree/master)

But it has no capability to get the [`Authorization Code Flow`](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/tutorials/code-flow) token itself. It needs to support by [`express`](https://expressjs.com/) server in local.

I will demo it can get me information, get artist and get playlist.
If you want to add more functionality, add it from [more examples](https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node/tree/master)

##### Demo code

Save as `get-spotify.js`

```js
const SpotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-node')
const express = require("express")
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express()
app.use(cors())

CLIENT_ID = "<your client ID>"
CLIENT_SECRET = "<your client secret>"
PORT = 8888 // it is located in Spotify dashboard's Redirect URIs, my port is 3000
REDIRECT_URI = `http://localhost:${PORT}/callback` // my case is 'http://localhost:3000/callback'

const spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
    clientId: CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
    redirectUri: REDIRECT_URI
})

SCOPE = [
    'user-read-private',
    'user-read-email',
    'user-library-read',
    'playlist-read-private',
    'playlist-modify-public',
    'playlist-modify-private'
]

app.get("/login", (request, response) => {
    const redirect_url = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&scope=${SCOPE}&state=123456&redirect_uri=${REDIRECT_URI}&prompt=consent`
    response.redirect(redirect_url);
})

app.get("/callback", async (request, response) => {
    const authorizationCode = request.query["code"]
    spotifyApi
        .authorizationCodeGrant(authorizationCode)
        .then((data) => {
            spotifyApi.setAccessToken(data.body['access_token'])
            spotifyApi.setRefreshToken(data.body['refresh_token']);
            tokenExpirationEpoch = new Date().getTime() / 1000 + data.body['expires_in'];
            response.send({
                access_token: data.body['access_token'],
                refresh_token: data.body['refresh_token'],
                'Retrieved token. It expires in ': Math.floor(tokenExpirationEpoch - new Date().getTime() / 1000) + ' seconds!'
            })
        })
})
app.get("/me", async (request, response) => {
    spotifyApi
        .getMe()
        .then((data) => {
            return response.send({me: data.body})
        })
})

app.get("/artist", async (request, response) => {
    const defaultArtistId = '19eLuQmk9aCobbVDHc6eek'
    const artistId = (request.query.artistId == null)?  defaultArtistId : request.query.artistId
    spotifyApi.getArtistRelatedArtists(artistId)
        .then((data) => {
            return response.send({ artist: data.body })
        })
})

app.get("/playlist", async (request, response) => {
    const defaultPlaylistId = '37i9dQZF1DX0tnKPLNG9Ld'
    const playlistId = (request.query.playlistId == null)?  defaultPlaylistId : request.query.playlistId
    spotifyApi.getPlaylist(playlistId)
        .then((data) => {
            return response.send({ playlist: data.body })
        })
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on :${PORT}`)
})
```

##### Install dependencies

```
npm install spotify-web-api-node express cors
```

##### Run it

```
node get-spotify.js
```

##### Login - should be do first by browser

```
http://localhost:8888/login
```

[image]

##### Get artist

```
http://localhost:8888/artist
```

If you want to use artist ID query

```
http://localhost:8888/artist/?artistId=0qeei9KQnptjwb8MgkqEoy
```

[image]

##### Get playlist

```
http://localhost:8888/playlist
```

If you want to use playlist ID query

```
http://localhost:8888/playlist/?playlistId=37i9dQZF1DX0tnKPLNG9Ld
```

[image]