# Getting connection refused errors when trying to hit a post route

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, vite

I am trying to use the spotify api in my music player project and every time I log in and get redirected to my /spotfylogin route in the console it says POST http://localhost:3001/spotifylogin net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

[error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScTDc.png)

This is my server js

```
// ==== [Cors] ====
app.use(cors());
const server = http.createServer(app);

//==== [Spotify] ====

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post("/spotifylogin", (req, res) => {
  const spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
    redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000/",
    clientId: "d67a6de2b2f045539acfef33cdff8840",
    clientSecret: "bd98e8446154499ab7eef56762cd16f2",
  });

  spotifyApi
    .authorizationCodeGrant(code)
    .then((data) => {
      res.json({
        accessToken: data.body.access_token,
        refreshToken: data.body.refresh_token,
        expiresIn: data.body.expires_in,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      res.sendStatus(400);
    });

  app.listen(3001);
});
```

this is my auth jsx

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default function spotifyAuth(code) {
  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState();
  const [refreshToken, setRefreshToken] = useState();
  const [expiresIn, setExpiresIn] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:3001/spotifylogin", { code })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
        setAccessToken(res.data.accessToken);
        setRefreshToken(res.data.refreshToken);
        setExpiresIn(res.data.expiresIn);
        window.history.pushStage({}, null, "/");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, [code]);
  return accessToken;
}
```

I have tried messing around with the cors cross origin but nothing has worked even tried proxy through vite config and that did not work either any help is appreciated

(NOTE: I am still fairly new to coding)

Comment: You should probably regenerate your token/secret now you've revealed them to everyone here.

Comment: right my fault will do that asap

Comment: your `redirectUri` needs to change  from `http://localhost:3000/` to `http://localhost:3000/callback` by Developer Dash board in [here](https://developer.spotify.com/) and the `SpotifyWebApi` example in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76731160/when-i-authenticate-with-spotify-my-url-returns-this-http-localhost8888-login/76741666#76741666)

Comment: @BenchVue i did that and im still getting a error connection refused like above

Comment: My point is just your server-side only not address the refuse issue. You need to address the server side first then address the CORS issue.

Comment: Can you push all code into github? I can review your code. current two sources not enough to reproduce your refuse issue.

Comment: @BenchVue https://github.com/kankanrr/connection-refused

Comment: I am not familiar with vite and react but I can display token on browser by my own server code. I can't push your repot. I will post in here. It is not answer but you can leverage from it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete solution but I just addressed server side issue.
Can you keep going the front side (vite and react part)

The `server.js` is locate new sub directory as 'express' directory.

./express/server.js

```
const SpotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-node')
const express = require("express")
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express()
app.use(cors())

CLIENT_ID = "your client ID"
CLIENT_SECRET = "your client secret"
PORT = 3000 // it is located in Spotify dashboard's Redirect URIs, my port is 3000 too
REDIRECT_URI = `http://localhost:${PORT}/spotifylogin` 

const spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
    clientId: CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
    redirectUri: REDIRECT_URI
})

SCOPE = [
    'user-read-private',
    'user-read-email',
    'user-library-read',
    'playlist-read-private',
    'playlist-modify-public',
    'playlist-modify-private'
]

app.get("/login", (request, response) => {
    const redirect_url = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&scope=${SCOPE}&state=123456&redirect_uri=${REDIRECT_URI}&prompt=consent`
    response.redirect(redirect_url);
})

app.get("/spotifylogin", async (request, response) => {
    const authorizationCode = request.query["code"]
    spotifyApi
        .authorizationCodeGrant(authorizationCode)
        .then((data) => {
            spotifyApi.setAccessToken(data.body['access_token'])
            spotifyApi.setRefreshToken(data.body['refresh_token']);
            tokenExpirationEpoch = new Date().getTime() / 1000 + data.body['expires_in'];
            response.send({
                access_token: data.body['access_token'],
                refresh_token: data.body['refresh_token'],
                'Retrieved token. It expires in ': Math.floor(tokenExpirationEpoch - new Date().getTime() / 1000) + ' seconds!'
            })
        })
})
app.get("/me", async (request, response) => {
    spotifyApi
        .getMe()
        .then((data) => {
            return response.send({me: data.body})
        })
})

app.get("/artist", async (request, response) => {
    const defaultArtistId = '19eLuQmk9aCobbVDHc6eek'
    const artistId = (request.query.artistId == null)?  defaultArtistId : request.query.artistId
    spotifyApi.getArtistRelatedArtists(artistId)
        .then((data) => {
            return response.send({ artist: data.body })
        })
})

app.get("/playlist", async (request, response) => {
    const defaultPlaylistId = '37i9dQZF1DX0tnKPLNG9Ld'
    const playlistId = (request.query.playlistId == null)?  defaultPlaylistId : request.query.playlistId
    spotifyApi.getPlaylist(playlistId)
        .then((data) => {
            return response.send({ playlist: data.body })
        })
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on :${PORT}`)
})
```

##### frontend

App.jsx

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Spotify />
  );
}
```

Spotify.jsx

```
import React from "react";

import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";

const SERVER_URL = "http://localhost:3000/login";
export default function Spotify() {
  return (
    <Container
      className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"
      style={{ minHeight: "100vh" }}
    >
      <a className="btn btn-success btn-lg" href={SERVER_URL}>
        Login with Spotify
      </a>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    port: 3005,
    open: true,
    proxy: {
      "/graphql": {
        target: "http://localhost:3001",
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Steps

#1 Install dependency at `express` directory

```
npm install spotify-web-api-node express cors
```

#2  Run server at `express` directory

```
node server.js
```

#3 Run client at `src` directory

```
npm run start
```

#4 Press Login in the browser
[image]

#5 Token will display
[image]

Again, this is not the whole solution, I just demo call from frontend and backend side login and display tokens, not return to frontend it.